# How to get NFC Card Emulation Transaction Event

Tags: android, nfc

How do I know in NFC Card Emulation Transaction Event that this is the event triggered by an applet in NFC USIM?

How do I capture the NFC Card Emulation Transaction Event in an Android application?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, as there are no public API's that support this.

Answer (score 0):

you cant do this with android but you can do it with blackberry service provider application

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/tkb/articleprintpage/tkb-id/java_dev@tkb/article-id/623
,

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/NFC-Card-Emulation-Primer/ta-p/1596893